# ServiceName And Name Differences?

Tags: azure

So I was lingering around my Azure account, and found some way to [set static IP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn630228.aspx).

Commands to set static IP is:

```
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName <service-name> -Name <name> | Set-AzureStaticVNetIP -IPAddress <ip-address> | Update-AzureVM
```

When I do:

```
Get-AzureVM -ServiceName <service-name> | Set-AzureStaticVNetIP -IPAddress <ip-address> | Update-AzureVM
```

; or:

```
Get-AzureVM -Name <name> | Set-AzureStaticVNetIP -IPAddress <ip-address> | Update-AzureVM
```

it still succeeded.

What's the **differences between ServiceName and Name?**

And, related question. **How do I list VMs that have IP address set to static?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495236.aspx):

-Service-name return information about all VM running in cloud service, -Name return info about exactly one VM.